# Retrieve all posts from matching meta_key using SQL

Tags: sql

So I'm building a query and I wanted to see how I can grab all the posts with the matching meta_key.

So I'm using this query to grab the below screenshot:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_10_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id';
```

So here is an example:

[image]

How could I output more tables such as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_10_postmeta, wp_11_postmeta, wp_12_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id';
```

Also, how can I retrieve the linked post_id particular to that post meta? So instead of outputting the `_taleo_id` results, I'd like for it to output the matching `post_id`?

Comment: Does these tables have same structure ?and the last part you said about linked post_id is not clear to me ?

Comment: Yes they do @Sujitmohanty30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correct, you can use `union all`,

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_10_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id'
union all
SELECT *
FROM wp_11_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id'
union all
SELECT *
FROM wp_12_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id'
```

Comment: This helps so much! So I get the `_taleo_id` output - Is there a way that I can use the `post_id` in wp_10_postmeta to display the linked wp_10_posts?

Comment: This was I added to the comments bit late? My question is from where to get `linked wp_10_posts`. I don't get it

Comment: So lets say that `wp_10_postmeta` outputs a `meta_key` that has `post_id` 252 .. how can I output that `post_id`? Would that have to call the `wp_10_posts` meta table? (This is all WordPress sorry).

Comment: Sorry if I am confusing you. So we do see post_id with above query and we agree on this part.right ? Now if we need something realated to this `post_id` from another table we can join this to each union then like...`SELECT m.*,p.linked_post_id
FROM wp_10_postmeta m join wp_10_posts  p on m.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id'`....